# cakephp complex find query example

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to perform a [find('all')](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#find-all) query on a table in a CakePHP application with the following conditions:

1- The primary key value is equal 17

AND

2- The value of another column `my_column_id` in the table is the MAX of all the values of the column `my_column_id` but less than the value of `my_column_id` of the datum whose primary key value is equal to 17

AND

3- The value of another column `my_column_id` in the table is the MIN of all the values of the column `my_column_id` but greater than the value of `my_column_id` of the datum whose primary key value is equal to 17

So the above query should give me 3 results.

Is it possible to get all this in one single query? or do I need three separate queries?

I tried something like:

```
$results = $this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'MAX(Model.my_column_id) <' => 23,
        'Mddel.id' => 17,
        'MIN(Model.my_column_id) >' => 23
    )
));
```

`23` represents the value of `my_column_id` of the datum whose primary key is equal to 17

But that gives me the following error: `SQL Error: 1111: Invalid use of group function`

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Often times when I have complex queries I'll just write out the SQL. I can't speak for the speed and I'm not sure if it's frowned upon, but you can try giving this a shot.

```
$this->Model->query('
    SELECT MAX(table.column), 
    MIN(table.column) 
    FROM table 
    WHERE table.id = '$id' 
');
```

Also, if this controller is outside of the model make sure to load the correct model (place it above the query)

```
$this->loadModel('Model');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MySQL aggregate functions (MAX, MIN etc) in your where clause.

I think the easiest way will be to explicitly include the GROUP BY and use HAVING, something like this:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'group' => 'Model.some_field HAVING MAX(Model.some_field) > 23 
        AND MIN(some_field) < 23'
));
```

(although that doesn't make sense, I don't think!)*

That's something like what you want.

Toby

**Update**

[*] By which I mean, I don't think it makes sense to be querying both *greater than* and *less than* a value!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by passing `conditions` array inside `find`.

**Example**

```
$this->Model->find('all',array
(
   'conditions' => array
   (
       'Model.field' => 17,
       'MAX(Model.field) < ' => 17,
       'MIN(Model.field) > ' => 17 
   )
))
```

**OP Comment Response**

`SQL Error: 1305: FUNCTION NAX does not exist`

**Solution**: Remove all spaces between the function and the parenthesis or set `sql_mode="IGNORE_SPACE"`;

This is causing the error:

```
SELECT MAX (id) as something FROM Example
```

This will work correctly:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as something FROM Example
```

Comment: Tried this already, does not work, I get an sql error saying `SQL Error: 1305: FUNCTION NAX does not exist`

Comment: @user765368 it should be `MAX` not `NAX`

Comment: Sorry about that, the error is actually the following `SQL Error: 1111: Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @user765368 problem is not in your pasted query...check for code inside model...and check association.